# coding for iphone 5 screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-5

I have taken a universal project. I have coded for iPhone 5 screen but it doesn't detect it.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //ui for ipad
}
else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,508);
    }
    else {
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,420);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work though. When I debug the code on iPhone 5 **screenBounds = 320*480**.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: nno need of frames ..... just set the Autoresizing.... :)

Comment: You no need to set the frame for tableview.. It automatically autoresizes

Comment: Your code should work as is. Did you set the Default.png for the 4" display in your info.plist?

Comment: you add Splash Screen for iphone 5.Default-568h@2x.png file then its work fine

Answer (score 3):

It is so simple to detect iPhone5 screen,
Just write

`#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)`

in your .pch file.... and you can further check for iPhone5 screen like `if(IS_IPHONE5)`.

Answer (score 1):

Choose your `UITableView` from the IB and select the size as `Retina 4` for all screens, even the main window xib file. This works fine even on the iphone 4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you add Splash Screen for iphone 5.Default-568h@2x.png file then its work fine

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me

```
  #define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

    if (IS_IPHONE_5)
        {
 //iphone 5
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to check iPhone 5 device.

```
float scrnheight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height ;

if(scrnheight == 568.0f)
{
    self.isIphone5 = true;
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the OP's version?

Comment: entirely ignored the code in question, replicated it and assumed that this would help? ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to detect iPhone 5 instead:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
   CGSize theHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
   if(theHeight.height == 568) {
        // iPhone 5
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,508);
   }
   else {
        // iPhone 4
        tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,420);
   }
}
```

Alternatively you can define this:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Which you can re-use whenever you need to find out if it's iPhone 5 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ::

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,508)];
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)
{
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320 ,420)];
}
```

Hope, it'll help you.

Thanks.